# PHP text-extraction from string

Tags: php, string, text-extraction

I have the following string: a:2:{s:4:"user";b:1;s:6:"userid";s:2:"48";}

What I need to do is extract number 48 from it, in this case. This number could have any number of digits. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are facing a serialized strings. So, instead of trying to get that number using regular expression or any other string manipulation methods, try this:

```
$myVar = unserialize('a:2:{s:4:"user";b:1;s:6:"userid";s:2:"48";}');
$myNumber = $myVar['userid'];
```

Learn about PHP serialization here:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php

Answer (score 1):

What *exactly* are you trying to achieve? That string looks like a `serialize()`d one, so your best bet would be to `unserialize()` it

Answer (score 1):

It looks like serialized string.

```
$data = unserialize('a:2:{s:4:"user";b:1;s:6:"userid";s:2:"48";}');
print_r($data['userid']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that's a serialized associative array. You just need to use unserialize() to turn it back from a string into an array.

```
<?php
  $arr = unserialize('a:2:{s:4:"user";b:1;s:6:"userid";s:2:"48";}');
  echo $arr['userid'];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The string I see is serialized array in PHP

To unserialize array do this

```
$obj = unserialize('a:2:{s:4:"user";b:1;s:6:"userid";s:2:"48";}');
echo $obj['userid'];
```

I have unserialized array then access array param by name